# Where query with uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to query for Answers that are correct = true and only grab one answer if they have the same question id. I was trying uniq or distinct.

```
@answers = Answer.where(id: params[:answer_ids])
@correct_answers = @answers.where(correct: true, question_id: distinct).count
```

How would you only grab one answer of any answers with the same question_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@answers = Answer.joins(:question).where(id: params[:answer_ids])
@correct_answers = @answers.where(correct: true).distinct(:question_id)
```

Comment: Well that does work but it doesn't answer the question. This just counts uniq after the query. I want the query to already have uniq question_ids

Comment: What you need is just `@answers.where(correct: true).distinct(:question_id)` and will get you distinct answer's per question.